# Quant Strategies on longer time frames

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading

I'm researching quant strategies suitable for retail traders, focusing on those beyond the typical 1-3 month holding period. Traditionally, retail strategies are influenced by insider information, market news, and analyst opinions, with quant approaches favoring timing-based methods like momentum, pairs trading, and mean-reversion for short durations.

I'm interested in expanding this horizon and exploring quant methodologies that are viable for longer time horizons.

Are there established or emerging quant strategies designed for holding periods of several months to a year or more?

Appreciate your replies!